# Angular 2 w3c validation

Tags: javascript, angular

There is some code of angular 2 code. It can't pass w3c validation because of the tag . Or angular library somehow changes the source in the end to make it valid?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    ...

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's "the tag"? What's the validation error?

Comment: tag <my-app>Loading...</my-app>

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this tag.

Comment: w3c validator says:
Element my-app not allowed as child of element body in this context.